# Calculate definite integral in R bunch of error

Tags: r, integral

I am trying to calculate the following integral, i.e there is an integral inside the integral.

```
integrate(function(v){
  integrate(function(s){
    pnorm(qnorm(v)-qnorm(s))
  },0,1)$value
},0,1)
```

Unfortunately I all the time get either:

```
Error in integrate(function(v) { : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

or:

```
 Error in integrate(function(s) { : maximum number of subdivisions reached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error because `integrate` needs a vectorized function. A workaround is to use `Vectorize` around the upper function.

```
integrate(Vectorize(function(v){
  integrate(function(s){
    pnorm(qnorm(v)-qnorm(s))
  },0,1)$value
}),0,1)

## 0.5 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```